# Ajax Delete request ReactJS and Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs

I have a component called Items that lives within a parents called ItemsContainer. When a button in Items is clicked an Ajax function is called to delete that Item.

At the moment however I am receiving a 500 error message and am not sure why.

**Item Component**

```
class Item extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
    super()

    this.state = { 
        name: '',
        price: 0,
        code: '',
        id: ''
    }
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
        name: this.props.data.name,
        price: this.props.data.price,
        code: this.props.data.code,
        id: this.props.data.id
    })
}

deleteItem() {
    let finalUrl = '/items/' + this.state.id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: finalUrl, /* THIS URL IS CALLING CORRECTLY ie. /items/8 */
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("successfully deleted");
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error");
        }
    })
}   


render(){
    let itemName = this.props.data.name
    let itemCode = this.props.data.code
    let itemQuantity = 1
    let itemPrice = (this.props.data.price * itemQuantity).toFixed(2)
    const itemId = this.props.data.id

    return(
        <tr>
            <td>{itemName}</td>
            <td>{itemCode}</td>
            <td>{itemQuantity}</td>
            <td><button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={this.deleteItem.bind(this)}>Remove</button></td>
            <td>£{itemPrice}</td>
        </tr>
    )
}
```

}

**Rails Items Controller**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)
    if @item.save
        render partial: 'items/item', locals: {item: @item}
    else
        render json: @item.errors.to_json
    end
end

def destroy
    if @item.destroy
        render partial: 'items/item', locals: {item: @item}
    else
        render json: @item.errors.to_json
    end
end

private

def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(
        :name,
        :price,
        :code,
        :id
    )
end
```

end

Creating a new Item is working as expected but I can't work out why I am receiving my 500 error for my delete action. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please check your destroy method in rail part. i think its lacking @item ? if i am right ?

Comment: Ah yes, thanks that's worked. I've used @item = Item.find(params[:id]) and it's working well now :)

Comment: Not sure of that though because have no experience will rails :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your destroy method in rail controller. 
There is no definition for @item hence 500 internal server error :)